# how to change the color of your divs, class names while editing in vscode

Tags: visual-studio, themes

[my current editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvVx0.png)

[how i want my editor to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryBOk.png)

you can see the different in colours
i want my  to have three  different colours for each of the words
how do i customise it according to the first picture
i tried to play around with themes and extensions but none is changing the semantic text in my .js file

https://jeffhykin.medium.com/how-to-customize-your-vs-code-text-colors-c0191155f41a
i dont' really know how to us this to change every single parameter and colour?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just look in extensions tab for "Themes".

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/configure there you got...